# Hosting free content for download by cross-platform app

Tags: android, ios, titanium, cross-platform

What are some good options for hosting free downloadable content for use in a Titanium app that will run on iOS and Android?

I know Apple allows you to host content for in-app purchases, however only some of my content will be paid, but majority will be free, so I need a way of hosting the free content.

The content is mostly audio files up to a maximum of 60Mb each with total of under 2 gigs of content.

Note: I don't want to stream the audio from the server, just download the audio files for use in the app.

I am looking for a solution that is cheap, easy to maintain, and scales well to lots of downloads (because you never know :)

Comment: are you just looking for suggestions for hosting providers?

Comment: I'm not necessarily just looking for suggestions for hosting providers (as thats not really a coding question suitable for stack overflow).  Rather, I was wondering whether there were any Platform-as-a-service solutions that might have the ability to manage as well as host your content (and meta-data about your content), as well as possibly help you manage your in-app purchases.

Answer (score 0):

Well... this is very subjective, and solution dependent. I personally use Amazon S3 for several projects. It can scale, is pretty cheap, and I've had reliable performance out of it. Easy to setup too.